# Theoretical Random Forrest question - Predicting winners of a competition - Teaching model to focus on accuracy of only one class prediction

Tags: random-forest

Apologies for the confusing title -

I've built a random forest model that predicts where someone is likely to finish in a competition based on about 50 variables and 12,000 observations.
People can finish from 1-20th (Example).

It's Accuracy across the entire population of prediction is encouraging. **However I'm only really concerned with trying to predict the winner.**

So while Overall accuracy is 70% prediction of the winner is only 40%.

My question is,
"Is it possible to ask the model to make tree decisions that are weighted towards achieving the greatest accuracy in winner prediction above all else..?"

I may be using the wrong model here (random forest) but am a little lost as to finding the answer.

Comment: what about switching from predicting the full rank of participants to simple binary winner 1 others 0.

Comment: Hey Mayeul - Awesome idea and I have done this and proves really useful in increasing usability :) (i basically grouped top 3 into "1" and rest into "0"). 

Still though, the Model is looking for overall accuracy in categorisation. Which i feel like is what a random forest is for. 

Just wish i could sort of create a preference for accuracy in the 1's and not the 0's even if it means using some other machine learning model

Comment: what about using a different metric for your model, like F1 for example

Comment: interesting, i will have to look into that... and how i could tune this/ a binary prediction model around this F1 score.

Comment: Random forest classifier doesn't take the metric as an input itself so you can fine tune your parameters to find the best performing parameters set given whatever metric you want to consider, or pick another classifier

Comment: @Mayeulsgc I actually found some success in Adding categorisations....
I broke up the competitors into top 2 next 2, next 2....bottom 2 etc.... the overall accuracy of the predicitons fell 

But the accuracy of the top 2 and bottom 2 grew by alot!

92% accuracy for the winners vs the 60% accuracy for the mid table